# PHP library for LIS tcpip

Tags: php, tcp

Is there a library for writing tcpclient in PHP for LIS in hospitals?
I have an automated instrument operated by server. I can communicate with the server using tcpip. My own database operate in MySQL with PHP.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you need it to do?  Why PHP?

Comment: Nobody is going to bother to google what "LIS" means. You should therefore add a link yourself, if you're asking for advises here.

Comment: Also, I'm somewhat uneasy that PHP might be used in hospitals.

Comment: LIS is Laboratory Information System. I am comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [socket](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) functions to connect to tcpip socket. But you would have to implement the LIS protocol yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can open sockets with PHP with [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

*Edit*: Michal has a link to the full socket "book," that might be more helpful.